# Java Stream Map of maps to map of maps with first map key

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to do one thing, but I do not understand how I can use the first key (`entry.getKey()`) in mapping.
The whole problem is that after mapping, the first key is the same as the second.
How can I say that `Map.Entry :: getKey = entry.getKey()`

```
LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, Parameter>> params = 
    new LinkedHashMap<>(DEFAULT_PARAMETERS.get(name));

Map<String, Map<String, Object[]>> collect = 
    params.entrySet().stream()
        .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue().entrySet().stream())
        .filter(en -> Objects.nonNull(en.getValue().getValues()))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, v -> 
            Map.of(v.getKey(), v.getValue().getValues())));
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your `flatMap` essentially discards the outer map’s key. You’d need to `flatMap` to a `Triple<Key, Key, Value>`.

Comment: I did not understand a bit, should I replace flatMap with Triple?

Comment: So I understand that you want to keep the top level keys, but it's not clear what you want to do with the components of the value `Map`s. Don't make us guess your intent from a code snippet, especially since you're aware that the code does not do what you intend it to.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this in a different way.

```
    LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, Object[]>> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for (Map.Entry<String, LinkedHashMap<String, kParameter>> p : DEFAULT_PARAMETERS.get(name).entrySet()) {
    LinkedHashMap<String, Object[]> collected = p.getValue().entrySet().stream()
            .filter(en -> Objects.nonNull(en.getValue().getValues()))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue().getValues(), (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));
    params.put(p.getKey(), collected);
}
```